# Python Splinter. How to select dropdown list which doesn't have name in option section

Tags: python, splinter

I try to select "Local Host" from the dropdown list which has the following html code:

```
<select id="server_select">
    <option></option>
    <option>
        Local Host
    </option>

    <option>
        ah005
    </option>

</select>
```

Here is my python code to use splinter module to select "Local Host" from dropdown list but failed.

```
server_list = browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@id="server_select"]//option[@selected="Local Host"]').first
server_list.click()
```

and I got the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splinter_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    server_list = browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@id="server_select"]//option[@selected="Local Host"]').first
  File "/Users/Bibo_MBPR/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 53, in first
    return self[0]
  File "/Users/Bibo_MBPR/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    self.find_by, self.query))
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with xpath "//select[@id="server_select"]//option[@selected="Local Host"]"
```

Could someone please give me some advice? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find_by_id` to get the browser element for drop down as it has the `id="server_select"` option. Then you can select your option from them by text. Try the following-

```
server_list = browser.find_by_id('server_select')
server_list.select_by_text("Local Host")
```

Or,

```
browser.find_option_by_text("Local Host").first.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Named options are usually very helpful. But when they don't exist you have to iterate over the options to find the right one.

```
dropdown = browser.find_by_xpath("//select[@id='server_select']")

for option in dropdown.find_by_tag('option'):
    if option.text == "Local Host":
        option.click()
        break
```

You may need to call `strip()` on `option.text` before comparing in case it contains extra whitespaces.

And in case that empty option at the top is causing you problems then I would change the `if` case to `option.text is not None and option.text == "Local Host"`.